# using captured groups in str_replace / stri_replace - stringi vs stringr

Tags: r, stringi

Most `stringr` functions are just wrappers around corresponding `stringi` functions. `str_replace_all` is one of those. Yet my code does not work with `stri_replace_all`, the corresponding `stringi` function.

I am writing a quick regex to convert (a subset of) camel case to spaced words.

I am quite puzzled as to why this works:

```
str <- "thisIsCamelCase aintIt"
stringr::str_replace_all(str, 
                         pattern="(?<=[a-z])([A-Z])", 
                         replacement=" \\1")
# "this Is Camel Case ain't It"
```

And this does not:

```
stri_replace_all(str, 
                 regex="(?<=[a-z])([A-Z])", 
                 replacement=" \\1")
# "this 1s 1amel 1ase ain't 1t"
```

Comment: One option would be `stri_replace_all(str,  regex = "(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])", replacement=" ")`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you look at the source for `stringr::str_replace_all` you'll see that it calls `fix_replacement(replacement)` to convert the `\\#` capture group references to `$#`. But the help on `stringi:: stri_replace_all` also clearly shows that you use `$1`, `$2`, etc for the capture groups.

```
str <- "thisIsCamelCase aintIt"
stri_replace_all(str, regex="(?<=[a-z])([A-Z])", replacement=" $1")
## [1] "this Is Camel Case aint It"
```

Answer (score 2):

The below option should return the same output in both cases.

```
pat <- "(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])"
str_replace_all(str, pat, " ")
#[1] "this Is Camel Case aint It"
stri_replace_all(str, regex=pat, " ")
#[1] "this Is Camel Case aint It"
```

According to the help page of `?stri_replace_all`, there are examples that suggest `$1`, `$2` are used for replacement

```
stri_replace_all_regex('123|456|789', '(\\p{N}).(\\p{N})', '$2-$1')
```

So, it should work if we replace the `\\1` with `$1`

```
stri_replace_all(str, regex = "(?<=[a-z])([A-Z])", " $1")
#[1] "this Is Camel Case aint It"
```